# Why are rows appearing in my new Nextjs app?

Tags: typescript, user-interface, next.js, frontend

I am just starting a project using Nextjs. I created it with the common command "npx create-next-app --ts". Once I remove the template UI and add my simple navbar at the top, I am left with a consecutive row UI. I don't have anything else on my code
[image]

Is this something to worry about?

Comment: Could you provide some code or some further detail, there is not enough here to answer your question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Delete this block of Code from your globals.css

```
body {
  color: rgb(var(--foreground-rgb));
  background: linear-gradient(
      to bottom,
      transparent,
      rgb(var(--background-end-rgb))
    )
    rgb(var(--background-start-rgb));
}
```